# Centering a layout with a background image not working in .kv

Tags: layout, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to use the kv language to create a layout. Currently, I am using the method recommended online to use a background image (utilizing a canvas.before and a rectangle), and now I am trying to add a button to the center of the page. However, no matter what layout or position/size hints I use, it refuses to center itself and stays in the bottom left corner of the screen.

I've tried putting it inside of an anchor layout and centering, I've tried putting that anchor layout inside of a floatlayout so it would automatically size it's children, but the result remains the same.

Here's what the .kv looks like:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<Game>: 
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'DefaultBackground.png'
    FloatLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'right'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            Button:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'y': .6}
                text:'Run'
                on_release: root.hello_world()
```

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: application representation]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the class of `Game`?

Comment: Note that [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint) is only handled by a `Layout`, and not all `Layouts`. So if `Game` is not a `Layout`, then `pos_hint` will have no efect.